# MYSQL Query: Search MYSQL database between 2 specific dates

Tags: mysql

I am trying to pull order information between 2 specific dates in my MYSQL database. The query I am running is this:

```
SELECT S.sku, COUNT(*), SUM(S.total), SUM(P.cogs)
FROM shopifyorders AS S JOIN products AS P ON S.sku=P.sku
GROUP BY S.SKU
WHERE S.sale_date BETWEEN "2015-1-01" AND "2015-01-04"
```

Now this is the line in question:

```
WHERE S.sale_date BETWEEN "2015-1-01" AND "2015-01-04"
```

I am trying to see all my orders between Jan 1st 2015 and Jan 4th 2015, but I keep getting a syntax error?

sale_date type is DATE

Any ideas why I keep getting an error?

**Edit:**

So I have another table and I ran a similar query:

```
SELECT SUM(cc_Fee)*-1
FROM shopifyorders AS s JOIN creditcardfees AS c ON s.order_id=c.order_id
WHERE s.sale_date BETWEEN "2015-1-01" AND "2015-01-07"
```

And it worked just fine and as expected, it leads me to believe I am doing something wrong with my syntax on first example? Can I use group by and where together?

Comment: The answer to "Can I use group by and where together?" is yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct query should look like this:

```
SELECT S.sku, COUNT(*), SUM(S.total), SUM(P.cogs)
FROM shopifyorders AS S JOIN products AS P ON S.sku=P.sku
WHERE S.sale_date BETWEEN "2015-1-01" AND "2015-01-04"
GROUP BY S.sku
```

"GROUP BY" have to be after the WHERE clause.